# Does the loop property of the sap.m.Carousel work?

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to enable the Carousel's `loop` feature.
In my view, I declare the property:

```xml
<Carousel height="auto" loop="true" pages="{ProductCollection}">
  <customLayout>
    <CarouselLayout visiblePagesCount="2" />
  </customLayout>
</Carousel>
```

It seems **not** to work!

Here's a sample of my code: https://embed.plnkr.co/zILEH3/

Comment: I can only loop backwards. Seems like a bug. I just created an issue in https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2656

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a bug that it worked backwards at all  which is [fixed](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/commit/7ccb18e11a03d6703fd47889ce030b5be3a7a523) by now..

According to the [note](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/1b3ee53b4e19454edd345ac2017be232832547e3/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/CarouselLayout.js#L34-L37) in the API reference, which I missed, the `sap.m.Carousel` was **designed to ignore** the loop if the `visiblePagesCount` is not `1`.

> **Note:** When this property is set to something different than the default value, the `loop` property of `Carousel` is ignored.